# Given a polynomial find the minimum value of the variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $x^5 - x^3 + x = a. $
Then we have to find the minimum value of $x^6$ in terms of a.
The answer given is $2a - 1$ if that gives any idea.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. 
A hint would do fine.

Comment: No other conditions?  So if $a=0$ we should expect $x^6=-1$?? to be the minimum?  I would be quite sure that $0$ would be the minimum then.

Comment: @Macavity I think it's like the lower bound for $x^6$.

Comment: There is considerable difference between calling something a minimum and lower bound.  I thought you wanted a minimum, which means there must be some value of $x \in \mathbb R$ which attains the value $2a-1$.

Comment: @Macavity Sorry then I really don't know and there's nothing else given in the question.

Comment: Express $x^6 = x(x^5 - x^3 + x) + x(x^3 - x) = ax + x^4 - x^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reinterprete the problem a bit differently (based upon the proposed answer) to show that
$$\tag1x^5-x^3+x=a\implies x^6\ge 2a-1. $$
Note that $(1)$ is trivially true for $a\le \frac12$. Hence we may assume that $a$ is positive.
We have $$(x^2+1)a=(x^2+1)(x^5-x^3+x)=x^7+x $$
so that $x$ must be positive. 
Divide by $x$ and subtract $1$ to arrive at 
$$x^6=\frac{(x^2+1)a}{x}-1\ge\frac{2xa}{x}-1=2a-1, $$
where we used $x>0$ and $x^2+1\ge 2x$ (from $x^2+1-2x=(x-1)^2\ge 0$).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Minimizing $x^6$ is the same as finding when $|x|$ is a minimum.  Hence we are looking for the real root with smallest absolute value, of $x^5-x^3+x = a$.

Now $x^5-x^3+x $ is strictly increasing, so for any value of $a$, there is only one real root (say $\alpha$) for the polynomial, and hence the minimum is simply $\alpha^6$.

Some cases are easy: $\alpha = a $ when $a \in \{0, \pm1\}$ for e.g.  Finding $\alpha$ as a simple function of $a$ does not seem feasible in general though.